# Как показать, что выводится float, если он хранит только целую часть?

Tags: c++, float, double, variable, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

На самом деле лучше показать на примере:

```
int a = 5;
float b = 5.7;
float c = 7;
std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
```

По факту получается `5 5.7 7`, а я хочу `5 5.7 7.0`. Можно ли это как-то реализовать? Мне не нужно форматировать все числа, например с std::scientific, мне нужно просто добавлять .0, если у float есть только целая часть.

С точки зрения реализации есть два метода, которые принимают int и float, поэтому сделать просто std::to_string(c) + ".0" не получится.

Comment: Смотрите iomanip

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    float b = 5.7;
    float c = 7;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << a << " " << b << " " << c;
}
```

Comment: а если b - 1.87656?

Comment: @JackyeJax, какой вывод вы хотите получить на числе `1.87656`?

Comment: Используйте другую точность. Только учтите, что 1.87656 в компьютере имеет вид 1.87656000000000000582645043323..., так что автоматически вычислить, сколько знаков выводить - у вас не очень-то получится...

Comment: Ну сколько вводилось, столько и должно выводиться кроме случая, когда во float'e нет мантиссы изначально

Comment: Вы отдаете себе отчет, что после ввода реально введенная строка преобразуется в число, которое при преобразовании обратно даст в общем случае другую строку? Вы введи что-то типа 1.234, а на самом деле сохраняется 1.23399996757507324. И как узнать, ввели вы 1,234 или что-то иное? см. https://ideone.com/BjjFxV Так, как вы хотите - "что ввели" - с числами с плавающей точкой не работает.